# Display on ElemtaryOS with an X1 ThinkPad

Tags: elementary-os, display, resolution, thinkpad

My Setup is a Thinkpad X1 2nd Generation (Europe) 20A.. Product ID.
Resolution 2560x1440.
I have installed ElementaryOS 0.3 (Freya).

My problem is now, when I connect a display via the Mini DisplayPort the Display get's "kind of" detected. It shows under Settings>Displays "Benq 22".
It renders the desktop background but in the wrong resolution.
The screens resolution is 1920x1080.
Another problem is that I cannot re-arrange the display in the display settings + I cannot change the display resolution in the display settings.

Last time I checked I installed the thinpad acpi packages, but I am not sure if they work correctly.

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-V (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev e4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 04)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 83)
```